# Umap import causes an exception: Numba needs NumPy 1.20 or less

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to import UMAP library in my lab work, however I get an error `ImportError: Numba needs NumPy 1.20 or less`. Before running the code, I checked that both packages are preinstalled and both packages have the latest version. Here is my code:

```
# Импорт базовых библиотек
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Визуализация

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Датасеты
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris  # для классификации
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston  # для регрессии

# Utils
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score

# Модели (классификация)
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Модели (регрессия)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Ridge
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.svm import SVR

# Метрики
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score, roc_auc_score  # для классификации
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error  # для регрессии

# Misc
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

# Для того, чтобы узнать возраст игрока
from datetime import datetime as dt

import umap

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
```

I will be very thankful if you help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of numpy is 1.22.3 as of 5th May 2022. You will have to downgrade your numpy package

Please run the below code and it should be resolved

```
pip install numpy==1.20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it: In addition to lowering the numpy version as required, the problem can also be solved by uninstalling and then reinstalling `numba`.

```
pip uninstall numba
pip install numba
```